# What could potentially affect some specific LoRa frequencies among others and how to mitigate it?

Tags: antenna, frequency, emc, snr, lora

I have started a small LoRaWAN network. I already have setup:

- 1x LoRaWAN gateway ([LAIRD RG186](https://www.lairdconnect.com/wireless-modules/lorawan-solutions/sentrius-rg1xx-lora-enabled-gateway-wi-fi-bluetooth-ethernet), using `EU863-870`);
- 4x T/RH Nodes ([Dragino LHT65](https://www.dragino.com/products/lora-lorawan-end-node/item/151-lht65.html), same standard);
- LoRa Servers to cope with packets and complete the dataflow.

Everything went fine, I am able to log packets from nodes scattered across the field.

Having collected data since few days, I have processed data with success. Now I am processing related metadata. My question mainly focuses on [RSSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication) and [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) and frequency plans.

If I draw a heatmap of packet counts, I can see that frequency plan changes and it is somehow homogenous:

[image]

If I draw heatmap with RSSI average, I get:

[image]

Which does not surprise me as `node-T002` and `node-T003` are most distant nodes in unfriendly environments (there are behind concrete walls).

But if I draw heatmap with SNR average, I get:

[image]

Which seems to points out that some frequency plan (`867.5 MHz` and `868.5 MHz`) are disadvantaged before others. And this is somehow surprising to me at the first glance.

Anyway, I have not enough background on this technology right now to clearly spot what is happening. My first thoughts are:

- There are some [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) (eg.: those frequency plans are to busy, maybe because to many other nodes emit on that frequencies);
- There are some scale issue, those frequencies are disadvantaged in this peculiar setup because of something else than EMI.

My question is: *Is there a know reason why this phenomenon occurs, how can I identify it and what could be done to mitigate it?*

Or more concisely, recalling the title: *What could potentially affect some specific LoRa frequencies among others and how to mitigate it?*

Comment: For best results, I think you should keep your payloads really small (<= 9 bytes), and use Adaptive Data Rate (ADR) and Over-the-Air-Activation (OTAA) so that the gateway can negotiate the Spreading Factor (SF) for Node do its best to optimize overall utilization of the spectrum and reduce congestion.

Comment: The frequency band you are using is open for all to use in Europe, therefore, all do use.  You may be seeing other devices operating on the channels that you point out.  You can use a spectrum analyzer to scan the spectrum to see just how busy it is (with your devices turned off of course).

Comment: @BEE, yes it does make sense. I have no spectrum analyser but I am listening frames on the gateway meanwhile my nodes are off. Maybe it will confirm this option. I'll update the post when I have information to add.